# SQL Server - Weird behavior in FTS

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with a column (`FullPath`) that can represent either a URL (e.g. `https://example.com/abc/123`) or a path in the file system (`/home/user/file.txt`)

When I use CONTAINS to perform full text search on that column, everything works great, until I start searching using dashes (`-`).

I know that dashes are known to cause issues with FTS (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/sql/admin/dashes-ignored-search-full-text-msidxs-queries), but I've noticed a strange behavior, and I wanted to know if that strange behavior is deliberate and whether I can take advantage of it or not.

I've noticed that when I have a `-` in my search term, it would consistently detect records that are URLs (begin with `something://`), but not so much if it's a file system path

For example, if my search term is `foo-bar`,

This will be detected,
`https://example.com/foo-bar/file.txt`

But this will not,
`/home/user/foo-bar/file.txt`

It looks like all records that begin with the pattern of `something://` will work nicely when the search term has `-`.

Is this behavior documented anywhere?

If so, would it be viable to take advantage of it and prepend something like `file://` to all of the file system paths?

Comment: It's not "strange behaviour" at all, it's by design; `-` is a "stop word" by default. `'foo-bar'` wouldn't be read as a single word, but as 2; `'foo'` and `'bar'`. You'll need to define your own stop list: [Configure and Manage Stopwords and Stoplists for Full-Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-stopwords-and-stoplists-for-full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Larnu I think OP is specifically referring to the fact that anything starting with `https://` seems to be parsed as a single word

Comment: @Larnu Isn't `/`also a stop word? I would expect search terms like `/home/user` to work though (they do). What makes `-` different than a `/`, and why adding `something://` at the beginning makes a difference?